# Object defined error in VBA for stock market feed

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am getting market feed for a particular stock in excel . So i am trying to copy the stock price in another cell. So For example X =56 is a stock price at say time t1.I am  copying that 56 in the cell say A50 and next time  t2 the stock price changes and I am copying that in cell say A 51 and it goes on. I wrote the code but I am getting error.

```
Sub CopyOpenItems()
Dim wbTarget
Dim wbThis
Dim WTF As Long
Dim FTW As Long
Dim X As Integer
X = 0

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equity").Activate
FTW = Cells(151, "F").Value
WTF = Cells(X, "F").Value

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
   FTW = WTF
   X = X + 1
   Loop
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Line `WTF = Cells(X, "F").Value` is wrong because `X` is zero and the row cannot be zero. Also the loop does not make too much sense and is not writing anywhere, I guess that you were looking for something on these lines:

```
   Dim maxX As Integer
   maxX = 100 'Max row you want to analyse
   Do While X <= maxX
        X = X + 1
        Cells(X, "F").Value = "whatever"
   Loop
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
   Dim sourceCol, destCol As String
   sourceCol = "A"
   destCol = "F"
   Do While Cells(X, sourceCol).Value <> ""
        X = X + 1
        Cells(X, destCol).Value = Cells(X, sourceCol).Value
   Loop
```

Comment: Thanks but now when i run the macro the feed is getting stopped .So i have to call from another excel and run this macro to access the feed

Comment: Cells() refers to the default worksheet (ActiveSheet) in the default workbook (ActiveWorkbook). If you are using various worksheets/workbooks, you should specify this issue (e.g., Workbooks("whatever").Sheets("whatever").Cells). Also it might be better to copy all the contents from the other workbook to temporary worksheets in the destination one.

Comment: Also... what you mean with "now when i run the macro the feed is getting stopped"? The suggestions above are fine, but have to be adapted to the specific situation you want to account for.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for your help. Just need to specify the workbooks name and sheet name and Cell name to copy